# Orientability on regular surfaces in R3

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I stumbled upon this post :

[Prove that orientable surface has differentiable normal vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049724/283136)

I can't do the connection between the determinant and the vector $N$ :( can someone fill in some more details?

Answer (score 0):

The right hand rule gives the answer. If the thumb is the normal vector, the two next fingers give the orientation.  Conversely,
 the orientation tells you if which normal vector is in the right direction.